# Deleting all objects which have a foreign key to another object in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table called User and another table called children. The children have a foreign key to the User table if they are a child of that user.

```
class Cild(db.Model):

   id = db.Column(
    db.Integer,
    primary_key=True,
    index=True,
    nullable=False,
    autoincrement=True,
    unique=True
   )
   bibliography_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                            db.ForeignKey('User.id'),
                            nullable=False)

   bibliography = db.relationship("User",
                               backref=db.backref('children',
                                                  cascade='all,delete-orphan',
                                                  lazy='dynamic'),
                               cascade='all,delete-orphan',
                               single_parent=True)

   def __repr__(self):
       return '<Cild %r>' % (self.id)
```

Now I want to delete all children for a User. I thought the cascade rule above would take care of that and I can just delete the User and all children will automatically be deleted, but that seems to not work.
So I did the very naive thing and tried

```
user = models.User.query.filter(id=1).first()
while True:
   if user.children.first() is None:
      break
   else:
      db.session.delete(user.children.first())
      db.session.commit()
print("user.children.first() = ", user.children.first())
db.session.delete(user)
db.session.commit()
```

The problem is that in some cases the print statement 'user.children.first()' is not None? It seems like some race condition, but since there is directly a commit after the child gets delete, I don't understand how? Does anybody know how to implement this robustly?

Comment: do you have other processes which works with `Cild` table?

Comment: no, only one process is running

Comment: could you explain why you are using `while`? as I see in your case will works `cascade deletion`. so you don't need iterations by children: `db.session.delete(user)
db.session.commit()` and that's it.

Comment: yes I agree... the while loop was a desperate attempt to make sure that there are really no connections in the db

Comment: also in your case queries works in different transactions. not sure is good approach.